# tikz - listings marker postion weird behavior

Tags: tikz-pgf, listings

I just add a marker dot on each line's start/first/end with build in marker coordinate but sounds like weird:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,varwidth=3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzmarklibrary{listings}
\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[name=lst1]
    line1
    line2
    line3
    line4
    \end{lstlisting}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \tikzset{dot/.style={circle,fill=red,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0}}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,4} {
        \node[dot,fill=red!50] at (pic cs:line-lst1-\i-start) {};
        \node[dot,fill=blue!50] at (pic cs:line-lst1-\i-first) {};
        \node[dot,fill=green!50] at (pic cs:line-lst1-\i-end) {};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Two issues:

1. If I set the start index to 0, I can see only the start point for the first line.
2. The first position of the the first line moved to the end.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing point on the first line is due to a bug in the code.  The purple dot is meant to be at the first *character* of each line, and to get to that I had to hook in to the code that places each non-space character on the page.  To target the *first* character, I use a conditional which is set to false when the mark is placed and reset to true at the end of the line.  Unfortunately, I forgot that LaTeX conditionals are false by default and so the conditional is not set to true at the start of the code, thereby meaning that it waits for the first end-of-line hook before it becomes active.

The solution is to set the conditional to be true at the start of the document.  Until this works its way into the published version (it is now on [github](https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark) but it generally takes me a little while to push to ctan), use the following in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\global\lst@linemarktrue
\makeatother
```

When you set the index to 0, what you are seeing is not the mark for the start of a line of code, but a mark for the start of the whole block of code.  I used the same naming convention as the marks at the starts of the lines for some reason that I don't actually remember now.  Probably because they all line up so it makes it easier to iterate over them all.  So there isn't a `first` or `end` mark because it isn't technically a line.

(Also, blank lines in code only get the `start` marker and not the `first` or `end` because those rely on there being actual text on the line.)

Comment: It works like a charm! still wish you can give more details about line 0 (start point is there but no first and end point)!

Comment: @lucky1928 Sorry - didn't see that part of the question (I was primarily responding to Schrodinger's cat's post).

Comment: @LoopSpace Would it be possible to also add a mark at the _end of the line_ (to know the width of the environment). In other words, to create the marks `begin`, `before_first`, `after_last`, `end` (maybe with other names). Thanks!

Comment: @PaulGaborit That would be a good idea, but I'm having trouble finding a suitable hook for the end of the line.  I can get the end of the *source* line (as seen by the `-end` marks) but if `breaklines` is set then I haven't found a way to get to the end of the actual line. Best I can do is a hook that is inside a `\discretionary` which gets processed after Every Single Character, but that seems to behave like `\mathchoice` in that each of its arguments is typeset into a box and only one box is placed. But if I step a counter in that box then it gets stepped every time and that's a *lot*.

Answer (score 3):

There are various issues. The randomly placed nodes come from the fact that the corresponding marks do not exist. `tikzmark` has a command that allows us to check whether or not a given mark exists, `\iftikzmark`. Installing these commands in your loop, which means that I essentially copied the example on p. 14 of the `tikzmark` manual, gives

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,varwidth=3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzmarklibrary{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[name=lst1]
    line1
    line2
    line3
    line4
\end{lstlisting}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \tikzset{dot/.style={circle,fill=red,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0}}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,4} {
        \iftikzmark{line-lst1-\i-start}{
            \node[dot,fill=red!50] at (pic cs:line-lst1-\i-start) {};
            }{\message{No start for \i^^J}}
        \iftikzmark{line-lst1-\i-first}{
            \node[dot,fill=blue!50] at (pic cs:line-lst1-\i-first) {};
            }{\message{No first for \i^^J}}
        \iftikzmark{line-lst1-\i-end}{
            \node[dot,fill=green!50] at (pic cs:line-lst1-\i-end) {};
            }{\message{No end for \i^^J}}
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

along with the warning

> No first for 1

You see that the randomly placed nodes disappear. However, I would agree with the statement that first *should* exist for the first line, too. Maybe this is an issue that should get reported.

BTW, your document gives the warnings

> Package varwidth Warning: Failed to reprocess entire contents on input
>   line 27. Package varwidth Warning: Failed to reprocess entire contents
>   on input line 27.

which seem unrelated to the missing first mark.

Comment: Hmmm. I agree that it should exist. I'll take a look.

Comment: @LoopSpace Would you please help clarify what's the reason the line 0 only start exist ?

Comment: @lucky1928 Too long for a comment, so posted as a separate answer.

Comment: @lucky1928 Please accept LoopSpace's answer instead of mine.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Sure, your answer is awesome as well. I never know such macro exist for code robust :-).

Comment: @lucky1928 Thanks!